# MySQL - SELECT … WHERE id IN (SELECT ...)

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (5,4,3,1,6)
```

and i want to get this value " 5,4,3,1,6 " from SELECT again.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT popuplarList FROM Settinng WHERE id =1 )
```

But i get only post number 5. I want to get all post from " 5,4,3,1,6 "

Is it possible to solve this with another logic or another way ?

thanks a lot

Comment: What does `SELECT popuplarList FROM Settinng WHERE id =1` return when you run it?

Comment: this value 5,4,3,1,6

Comment: please double-check the name of the table in the query. Look like the Settinng name is wrong

Comment: when i check SELECT popuplarList FROM '.SETS.' WHERE id = 1

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [popuplarList] => 6,7,8,9
        )

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below:

- 1st solution:

```
    select * 
    from table 
    where (
        select CONCAT(",", popuplarList, ",")
        from Settinng where id = 1
    ) like concat("%,", id, ",%")
```

- 2nd solution:

```
    select * from table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`id`, (
       select CONCAT(",", popuplarList, ",") from Settinng where id = 1)
    )
```

Comment: To make it a useful answer you have to explain why you think that the approach of the OP does not work and why your solution will solve that problem.

Comment: I think in his data, popuplarList is saved as text, list id, and separated by comma

Answer (score 3):

Try FIND_IN_SET Method

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, (SELECT popuplarList FROM Settinng WHERE id =1 ))
```

Comment: @wayan wahyu Adi Putra, please try this method , mayb be help you !

Comment: To make it a useful answer you have to explain why you think that the approach of the OP does not work and why your solution will solve that problem.

Comment: Great ! @wayan wahyu Adi Putra

Comment: `I did not say to try any wrong answer` Where did I say that? I said that you should explain why `FIND_IN_SET` behaves differently than using `IN`. Just saying to use `FIND_IN_SET` instead does not help to understand why this is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM table INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT popuplarList FROM Settinng WHERE id = 1
) AS q ON table.id = q.popuplarList;
```